# Valid Distribution profiles vanish from the Xcode Organizer?

Tags: xcode, distribution, code-signing, provisioning, xcode4.2

Since 2 weeks ago, every time I manually add any Distribution Profiles (Ad-Hoc or AppStore Profiles) to Xcode, they vanish from the Organizer in a matter of minutes, or when I press the Refresh button (the one next to "Automatic Device Provisioning" in Organizer).

How do I solve this problem?

(note that I've already tried to start fresh without success: cleaning KeyChain Access, revoking certificates, deleting profiles, and do it all step by step since the beginning)

Comment: Before they vanish from Xcode do they work?

Comment: Yes, but it happens to ALL distribution profiles, although there is no problem with Development profiles.

Comment: Have you found an explanation for this by any chance? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: Same problem here; it's driving me mad. I've offered a bounty for an answer to this.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple, who have replied to say it's a known issue and a fix is being worked on - great news! If anyone knows of a workaround in the meantime I'd love to hear it.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the workaround that worked for me was to clean like you did, then _disable_ automatic provisioning, and finally add the profiles manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not logged in as the "Team Agent" in XCode, that might explain the reason why the distribution provisioning profiles are disappearing.

Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not the case here; I am logged in as the Team Agent. I'm on Xcode 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for several weeks also. I think this was a bug with Apple's provisioning back-end. Today the Member Center was down for maintenance. When it came back up I did refresh from the organizer and all my Ad Hoc and Distribution profiles were automatically imported (as it should be).

Try a refresh from inside the organizer and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now facing such kind of issue, In the previous version of xcode, it works fine, But when I upgrade to 4.3.2, distribution profile missed, tried many ways, but all failed.
I have not removed previous version of xcode, but same issue happened.
Suggest to not upgrade to latest xcode version, I will pending until facing blocking next time, My product has been delayed because of this issue, what a pity.